# Android ListView Default Divider Styles / Attributes

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, divider

I have a LinearLayout view that I am trying to add a divider to so that it looks exactly the same as the default ListView control.  I am trying to replicate the edit contact within the default Android (Nexus S 2.3.3) Contacts app and I believe a LinearLayout would be best for performance.

I am using the code to replicate the divider as shown below:

```
    <View
    android:id="@+id/Separator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dividerHeight"
    android:background="?android:attr/divider"/>
```

How can I access the default divider color or drawable and also the divider height?  I would like this to match the ListViews I have setup, so using the Android system attributes would be best I think.  The above code crashes as shown below so I assume I can't access those attributes or am going about this incorrectly.

```
03-13 22:59:38.851: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3575): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #26: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is how it's done in [Android source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=res/layout/item_kind_section.xml;h=d1dec5e9583828a528f78afb484b0b5c361d4032;hb=HEAD)

```
<View android:id="@+id/Separator"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
```

Comment: how to get all this default values of android as you have mentioned in above answer i.e.?android:attr/listDivider ?

Comment: I have the same question as Hunt: where did you get that value exactly?

Comment: Is this same for ListView ?

Answer (score 0):

The source of Magician Knowledge must be https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html

> public static final int listDivider:
>
> The drawable for the list
>   divider. Must be a reference to another resource, in the form
>   "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name".

So all I have to do type in that site search bar - "drawable for the list divider" or just "divider"